# Availability groups and Linked Servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, linked-server

I have inherited an Availability Group and have found that a linked server was set up between the two nodes of the availability group. It is using `sa` for authentication unfortunately.

Simultaneously, some of the team's developers use `sa` to query the live DB. I want this to stop.

**My question is:**

Are linked servers in any way required by availability groups? I know I have some bespoke moving parts like Agent jobs that use the linked server to sync jobs between the two nodes. I'm more concerned about something internal to SQL Server that I might not be aware of. Anything wrong with just doing normal due diligence and changing the linked server user to use non-sa and also changing the `sa` password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are linked servers in any way required by availability groups?

Absolutely not needed by SQL Server for Availability Groups!

> Anything wrong with just doing normal due diligence and changing the linked server user to use non-sa and also changing the sa password?

No, I agree with your approach as long as it doesn't break the business requirements. However, if the developers are using it to query around then I could argue that they should be changing their software to do this, rather than a linked server.

I would tend to agree that it's most likely used to automagically sync logins and jobs, but again there is no need for an actual linked server to do this though I could see why they would use a highly privileged account so they wouldn't have to worry about permissions.